# VBA -find in range with multiple conditions to color field

Tags: vba, excel, find, date-range

i have been trying to create a vba code to check if in each range of the cell selected i have 2 conditions. If both conditions are met, i want to color it. i wrote it like this:

```
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
Selection.Activate
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In ThisRng.Cells
    With cel
   cel.Find("..condition1 to search").Activate
    ActiveCell.Find("...secondcondition").Activate
     ActiveCell.Select
     ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
     ThisRng.Activate

   End With

Next cel
```

This works only when i am having the conditions true. if the cell cannot be activated, it gives me an error and is does not move to next cell.

Any ideas, please?

Thanks

Comment: You want to check two conditions in each cell of selected range?

Comment: in the selected range i want to color the background cell if in the cell i find round and if it ends with "/*,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would colour any cell red that has a Round Formula that ends ",0)"

```
Sub Demo
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In ThisRng.Cells
   if len(cel.formula)>6 then
       if left(cel.formula,6)="=ROUND" and right(cel.formula,3) = ",0)" then
            cel.interior.ColorIndex = 3
       end if
    end if
next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: is something similar, but the check i have to make is if in the cell i have round formula and if it ends with "/*,0)

Comment: It is working, but only if i have round at the beginning of the formula. There are situations were round has  another formula in front. Thank you a lot for the end checking version, i did not know how to do it. So in the if i should have a find function (which i don't know how to write and the right(cel.formula,3) = ",0)"

Comment: in vba you use the INSTR(  ) function so the first clause would rewrite to 
    if  INSTR(cel.formula, "ROUND") > 0  and...

Comment: thank you, it worked written like that. one more question, if possible. for  right(cel.formula,3) = ",0)" i have to check if at the end i have "/*,0)" and the star is a cell that is changing, for example /$L66,0). i tried using wildcards, but is not working. How can i write this, please?

Comment: got it in the end: Right(cel.Formula, 8) Like "/$*,0)"  works to identify the cells. Thank you a lot for your help in figuring this out.